# Why do I get an error on Input out of range exception?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, logic

```
int bNum=3;
int aNum=3;
for (int i = 0; i < bNum; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < aNum; j++)
            {
                b[i] += a[j];
                b[i + 1] += a[j + 3];
                b[i + 2] += a[j + 6];
            }
        }
```

I basically want the following to happen:

```
b[0]=a[0]+a[1]+a[2];
b[1]=a[3]+a[4]+a[5];
b[2]=a[6]+a[7]+a[8];
```

What is wrong with my logic?

HAHA! OOPS! My sleepy eyes are accounting for the dumb question. I see that at every iteration it get computed multiple times.

Comment: What are the size of the arrays? That `i+3` is probably going above it.

Comment: You're using `b[i + 6]` as an index. I assume you meant `b[2] = a[j + 6]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

whatever language it is, you need to make constant index for b, variable index for a

```
 for (int j = 0; j < aNum; j++)
        {
            //here is loop-unrolling for b
            b[0] += a[j];
            b[1] += a[j + 3];
            b[2] += a[j + 6];
        }



  for(k=0;k<max;k++)
  {
  for (int j = 0; j < aNum; j++)
        {
            //without loop-unrolling
            b[k] += a[j+k*3];

        }
   }
```

i made the "k" loop outer to let it read the a[] as continuously as possible. You can make "k" loop innerside but it makes reads of a[] jumping from here to there then coming back here again an jumping again, which makes it slow.
this is not a vector though :P i just used it to fill the space

Comment: Thank you! I was really tired and couldn't think straight. But I like your vectorized idea!

Answer (score 1):

The question is kind of contradictionary. 
The *length* of both arrays is equal, but the requirement stands to not have equal.

*Assuming* that the **requeirement** is correct, you can do the following

For every `b` element there is a **sum** of the *next* 3 elements of the `a`

```
int bNum=3;    
int aIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bNum; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)      
       b[i] += a[aIndex ++];

}
```

There is no any array bounds control here. This is just a *sample* code naturally.

If this is not what you're searching for, please clarify.